# Google Places API Return Postcode

Tags: c#, json, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to get the postcode of the returned Google Places API.

I've looked everywhere but can't seem to find a working example of how people do it.

Here's my API that runs fine in Postman:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Sydney&region=AU&key=xxxxx&libraries=places
```

Here's the sample JSON response

```
{
   "predictions": [
      {
         "description": "xxxxx",
         "place_id": "xxx",
         "reference": "xxx",
         "structured_formatting": {
            "main_text": "xxx",
            "main_text_matched_substrings": [
               {
                  "length": 2,
                  "offset": 0
               },
   ],
   "status": "OK"
}
```

How do I get the postcode details as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, found the solution.

Need to use another API endpoint and insert the place_id like so:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?region=AU&key=xxx&place_id=xxxx
```